Is it possible to somehow make the event count metric a dimension in an exploration in ga4?
Sorry if this is a really silly question but I am hoping someone will be able to help me. I am new to ga4 so please forgive any misunderstanding.
What am I trying to do? Basically, I have a custom event that has multiple time parameters (measured in seconds), which are all setup to be custom metrics. I need a graph for this event to show each custom parameter per event count. So each column has the time parameter and each row is the custom event count.
(the custom event is from the Unity Firebase SDK)
I have set it up so the current dimension is filtering by event name, but just one row shows up with a total time amount for each custom parameter (which is expected, but not what I need). (see image)
current exploration
Is there anyway to do what I want to do? I know that you can't add a metric as a dimension, but just wondering if there is any kind of work around to get what I need.
